# rounding through rule of significant digit

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to apply the rules of significant digit  to a Excel sheet, that is printing values from Macros?

Or in any way the values calculated by VBA Macros go through significant digit rule and are than printed on excel sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a formula for significant figures:

```
=ROUND(REFERENCE,SIGFIGS-1-INT(LOG10(ABS(REFERENCE))))
```

For example, if you want the value in A1 to be 3 significant figures, you would put:

```
=ROUND(A1,2-INT(LOG10(ABS(A1))))
```

EDIT: I just threw together a quick VBA macro to do it to every cell in a selection if you want:

```
Sub ConvertToSigfigs()
    Dim Sigfigs As Integer
    Sigfigs = 3 'Change this to whatever value you want
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In Selection
        cel.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(cel.Value, Sigfigs - 1 - Int(Application.WorksheetFunction.Log10(Abs(cel.Value))))
    Next
End Sub
```

Note I used the Application.WorksheetFunction.Round() instead of VBA's Round() so it would work with non-decimal numbers.

EDIT 2: And here's a UDF:

```
Function Sigfig(Inpt As Double, Precision As Integer) As Double
    Sigfig = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Inpt, Precision - 1 - Int(Application.WorksheetFunction.Log10(Abs(Inpt))))
End Function
```

EDIT 3: The one thing this won't do is keep terminal zeroes, e.g. if you have 4.0001 and round to three sig figs, excel will display 4, not 4.00. It would be possible to add formatting in the sub based on modulos, if that's absolutely required.

A neat project would be to use a UDF, and then have a sub that would parse the UDF afterwards to convert it to an Excel formula so you wouldn't have to save as .xlam.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a VBA user defined function to do Scientific Rounding with significant digits or a limited number of decimals and this is what I put together to use in a macro.

To use on a worksheet like '=SciRound(B3,3)' press Alt + F11 to open the Visual Basic Editor and from the Insert Menu add a Module.  Copy/Paste the code into Module1 then use
like '=SciRound(Number or Cell Location to round, SigFigs, decimal places)'

```
Public Function SciRound(number, sigfigs, Optional decimals As Variant)
'      Nov2013 TP
Dim exp As Integer, n As Integer
Dim bdec As Boolean, test As Variant

If (IsEmpty(number) Or IsMissing(number)) = True Then SciRound = CVErr(xlErrNull)
If IsNumeric(number) = False Then SciRound = CVErr(xlErrValue)

If (IsNumeric(sigfigs) = False) Or (sigfigs < 1) Then SciRound = CVErr(xlErrValue)

If (IsMissing(decimals) Or IsEmpty(decimals)) = True Then bdec = False Else bdec = True
If bdec = True Then
  If (IsNumeric(decimals) = False) Then SciRound = CVErr(xlErrValue)    
  If (Int(decimals) <> decimals) Then SciRound = CVErr(xlErrNum)
End If

If IsError(SciRound) = True Then Exit Function
If number = 0 Then SciRound = 0: Exit Function

number = CDec(number): test = Abs(number): n = 0
n = Int((Log(test) / Log(10#)))  '  natural log to log10
exp = (sigfigs - n) - 1

If bdec = True Then
 If (exp < decimals) Then bdec = False
End If
If bdec = True Then
 SciRound = Round((number * 10 ^ decimals), 0) * 10 ^ -decimals
Else
 SciRound = Round((number * 10 ^ exp), 0) * 10 ^ -exp
End If
End Function
```